# Lagom external Cassandra authentication

Tags: cassandra, akka, lagom

I have been trying to set up an external Cassandra for my Lagom setup.

In root pom I have written

```
                    <configuration>
                        <unmanagedServices>
                            <cas_native>http://ip:9042</cas_native>
                        </unmanagedServices>
                        <cassandraEnabled>false</cassandraEnabled>
                    </configuration>
```

In my impl application.conf

```
akka {
persistent {
  journal {
  akka.persistence.journal.plugin = "this-cassandra-journal"

      this-cassandra-journal {
        contact-points = ["10.15.2.179"]
        port = 9042
        cluster-id = "cas_native"

        keyspace = "hello"

        authentication.username = "cassandra"
        authentication.password = "rodney"
        # Parameter indicating whether the journal keyspace should be auto created
        keyspace-autocreate = true

        # Parameter indicating whether the journal tables should be auto created
        tables-autocreate = true
      }
  }

  snapshot-store {
    akka.persistence.snapshot-store.plugin = "this-cassandra-snapshot-store"

      this-cassandra-snapshot-store {
        contact-points = ["10.15.2.179"]
        port = 9042
        cluster-id = "cas_native"

        keyspace = "hello_snap"
        authentication.username = "cassandra"
        authentication.password = "rodney"
        # Parameter indicating whether the journal keyspace should be auto created
        keyspace-autocreate = true

        # Parameter indicating whether the journal tables should be auto created
        tables-autocreate = true
      }
    }

}
```

But I get the error

```
[warn] a.p.c.j.CassandraJournal - Failed to connect to Cassandra and initialize.
 It will be retried on demand. Caused by: Authentication error on host /10.15.2.
179:9042: Host /10.15.2.179:9042 requires authentication, but no authenticator f
ound in Cluster configuration
[warn] a.p.c.s.CassandraSnapshotStore - Failed to connect to Cassandra and initi
alize. It will be retried on demand. Caused by: Authentication error on host /10
.15.2.179:9042: Host /10.15.2.179:9042 requires authentication, but no authentic
ator found in Cluster configuration
[warn] a.p.c.j.CassandraJournal - Failed to connect to Cassandra and initialize.
 It will be retried on demand. Caused by: Authentication error on host /10.15.2.
179:9042: Host /10.15.2.179:9042 requires authentication, but no authenticator f
ound in Cluster configuration
[error] a.c.s.PersistentShardCoordinator - Persistence failure when replaying ev
ents for persistenceId [/sharding/ProductCoordinator]. Last known sequence numbe
r [0]
com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.AuthenticationException: Authentication erro
r on host /10.15.2.179:9042: Host /10.15.2.179:9042 requires authentication, but
 no authenticator found in Cluster configuration
        at com.datastax.driver.core.AuthProvider$1.newAuthenticator(AuthProvider
.java:40)
        at com.datastax.driver.core.Connection$5.apply(Connection.java:250)
        at com.datastax.driver.core.Connection$5.apply(Connection.java:234)
        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.Futures$AsyncChainingFuture.doTrans
form(Futures.java:1442)
        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.Futures$AsyncChainingFuture.doTrans
form(Futures.java:1433)
        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.Futures$AbstractChainingFuture.run(
Futures.java:1408)
        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.Futures$2$1.run(Futures.java:1177)
        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.MoreExecutors$DirectExecutorService
.execute(MoreExecutors.java:310)
        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.Futures$2.execute(Futures.java:1174
)
```

I also tried providing this config

```
lagom.persistence.read-side {
  cassandra {
  }
}
```

How to make it work by providing credentials for Cassandra?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Lagom, you may already use `akka-persistence-cassandra` settings for your `journal` and `snapshot-store` (see reference.conf in the [source code](https://github.com/akka/akka-persistence-cassandra/blob/v0.23/src/main/resources/reference.conf#L164-L167), and scroll down for `cassandra-snapshot-store.authentication.*`). There's no need to configure it because Lagom's support for Cassandra persistence already declares `akka-persistence-cassandra`as the Akka Persistence implementation:

`akka.persistence.journal.plugin = cassandra-journal
akka.persistence.snapshot-store.plugin = cassandra-snapshot-store`

See https://github.com/lagom/lagom/blob/c63383c343b02bd0c267ff176bfb4e48c7202d7d/persistence-cassandra/core/src/main/resources/play/reference-overrides.conf#L5-L6

The third last bit to configure when connecting Lagom to Cassandra is Lagom's Read-Side. That is also doable via `application.conf` if you override [the defaults](https://github.com/lagom/lagom/blob/c63383c343b02bd0c267ff176bfb4e48c7202d7d/persistence-cassandra/core/src/main/resources/reference.conf#L62-L65).

Note how each storage may use a different Cassandra Ring/Keyspace/credentials/... so you can tune them separately.

See extra info in the [Lagom docs](http://www.lagomframework.com/documentation/1.3.x/java/PersistentEntityCassandra.html#Configuration).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I changed my cassandra version to 3.0 and it started working. However I have few queries, firstly my project is in maven. I dont get to know from any debug logs whether it actually connected to Cassandra or not. Also my keyspace is not present in Cassandra server I am running. When I ran an sbt project, I saw keyspace getting created and also some debug logs. Secondly does cluster-id  always have to be "cas_native"?